# Screenshot of Scene in UIStoryboard

Tags: ios, image, screenshot, uistoryboard, scene

Is there an easy way of taking a screenshot of a scene / uiviewcontroller in the storyboard?  I know you can take a screenshot from the simulator, but I would like to take a picture from storyboard and post the image on stackoverflow.

Comment: why don't you take a screenshot using Preview? (Preview: File -> Take Screenshot -> from Selection.). BTW, Snapshots are [are different than what you think](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-structure_navigator/articles/RestoringaProjectorWorkspacefromaSnapshot.html).

Comment: Didn't know you could take a screenshot from Selection.  Thanks!

Comment: How do I accept it as a comment?

Comment: While I appreciate the generosity, @robmayoff put as an answer what I put as a comment. You should accept his answer, I think it would be dumb if I posted a duplicate answer.

Comment: Okay, no problem.  Sorry, Captain :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode doesn't have a function for creating an image of a storyboard scene.

Use Mac OS X's built-in support for taking screen shots.  The default shortcut to take a picture of a rectangle on the screen is <kbd>⌘⇧4</kbd>, and it places the picture on your desktop.  See [this Q&A](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/92870/98331) on Ask Different for more shortcuts.

Comment: The list of shortcuts is great.  Thank you!